# Combobox issues in Click

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my application for one form I'm using grid to enter the details. During past days it not gave any issues. Now it is giving some thread issues in exe saying like `thread state408` issues.

It is happening in first click of the combobox in grid.

Comment: Please post your code. It is quite difficult to read through the lines and get your problem. Thanks

Comment: @BadChallenge You must have messed with threads "during past days". Unless you isolate the problem and post some code, it is unlikely that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following changes in program.cs file

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
Application.Run(new FlashForm());
```